# Missing template on passing variable to controller action from AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to pass a variable from AJAX(JS file) to controller#action. But it doesn't pass and returns error of "Missing template". How can I fix this problem?

My AJAX code:

```
function message_for(username){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/show_message',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        to: username
    },
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
  })
}
```

Def show_message:

```
def show_message
    @to = params[:to]
    Message.all_messages(@to)
end
```

Routes:

```
post '/show_message' => 'messages#show_message'
```

But it doesn't work.
The error log prints:

```
Started POST "/show_message" for 194.135.153.182 at 2015-01-09 09:37:45 -0500
Processing by MessagesController#show_message as */*
Parameters: {"to"=>"alizade"}
Completed 500  in 13ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template messages/show_message, application/show_message with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/usr/local/projects/bookworm/app/views"
):
```

Comment: What do you want your response from the controller to be? Since you aren't specifying one, it is trying to render the `show_message` template, which apparently doesn't exist.

Comment: @ptd Message.all_messages(@to) this line must return `message_text`. So I want to alert it

Comment: please change change it `GET` instead of `POST` and try to execute

Comment: I think you need to wrap that in a `respond_to` block, `resond_to do |format| format.json { render json: Message.all_messages(@to) } end`. Sorry for formatting but you get the idea. I would also move `Message.all_messages(@to)` and assign it to a variable so it isn't in the `respond_to` block.

Comment: @CWitty can you show me an example of it? Answer please to my question below with example code. This would be very helpful for me in the future, too.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to replace 'POST' with 'GET' request (omit the `method` property and you have it by default). You also need to use `render plain`.

Here is a sample implementation of your controller action:

```
def show
  text_to_alert = 'Hello There'
  render plain: text_to_alert
end
```

Now fill in the `text_to_alert` with whatever text content you want to alert.

Your ajax call should be something like that:

```
var url = '/messages/show';
var username = 'foo_username';
var data = {
  to: username
};
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data);
        }
});
```

This is an indicative implementation, but you get the idea.

I have implemented a sample Rails project that demonstrates the above and it works. Here it is: [ajax_get_request_example](https://github.com/pmatsinopoulos/ajax_get_request_example).